# How to save Selection globally

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to store and restore user selection through google app script.I want to save this selection globally so any time I can retrieve selection and show on document.
I have tried with using Properties service(user Property) to store.when I tried to get properties service by key it returns me the string object.How I can convert it to class object?

How I can retrieve User selection?
Thanks for help in advance..

Comment: Use `var myObject = JSON.parse(object as string);` to convert a string back to an object.  Properties service converts everything to a string before saving it.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your answer but getSelection returns me the range Object not a JSON.I need to convert back to Selection Object to show Selecton.

Comment: You have not provided any code.  You mentioned the `getSelection()` method in your comment, but not in the main question.  Also, if your question is related to Google Docs, then add that tag.

Answer (score 1):

You need to clear up your answer. Based on what I have read in the question **and** the comments you wish to store a Range object. Properties will not maintain object data and it does not work with JSON well because it is a Google specific object and does not follow the JSON (which merely stands for JavaScript Object Notation).

What I would do in your case is store the information you can use to rebuild that. So you need the start row, column and the numRows and numColumns (`getRow()`, `getColumn()`, `getNumRows()` and `getNumColumns()` respectively). Store those integers either as an array or a JSON object. Then when you restart the script simply rebuild the range with `getRange()` and those integer variables.